# Supabase JavaScript Client multiple joins

Tags: javascript, join, supabase

I am facing a problem with my supabase + Nuxt application
In Supabase I have setup the following tables. Users, Events and a many-to-many reference table called Guests.

- 1 User can host 1 event
- n Users can be guests at n events

> ```
> users = {
>     id: string,
>     name: string,
> },   
> events = {
>     id: string,
>     title: string,
>     host: id(foreign key -> users),
> }
> guests = {
>     user_id: id(foreign key -> users),
>     event_id: id(foreign key -> events),
> }
> ```

Now I want to query my backend using JS.

```
client.from('events').select('id, title, host, users(id, username)').eq('host', user.value.id)
```

the Response looks like this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "BBQ",
  "host": "5528a25b-6e38-4996-a1f6-24abf4501c39",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "207d27e7-a65e-4d9e-93c9-b8fde509ce4f",
      "username": "Alex"
    },
    {
      "id": "94ec00b6-340f-4dc2-ab9b-f94a2f34c31f",
      "username": "Bernd"
    },
    {
      "id": "e357c7ff-941c-4f7d-9596-5dabc170fb15",
      "username": "Cedric"
    }
  ]
}
```

the guests are resolved properly. Now I want to resolve the host but I have no idea how to do so.

what I tried was this

```
client.from('events').select('id, title, host:profiles(id, username), users(id, username)').eq('host', user.value.id)
```

I have expected to get this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "BBQ",
  "host": {
      "id": "5528a25b-6e38-4996-a1f6-24abf4501c39",
      "username": "John"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "207d27e7-a65e-4d9e-93c9-b8fde509ce4f",
      "username": "Alex"
    },
    {
      "id": "94ec00b6-340f-4dc2-ab9b-f94a2f34c31f",
      "username": "Bernd"
    },
    {
      "id": "e357c7ff-941c-4f7d-9596-5dabc170fb15",
      "username": "Cedric"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I got that

```
   {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "BBQ",
      "host": [
        {
          "id": "207d27e7-a65e-4d9e-93c9-b8fde509ce4f",
          "username": "Alex"
        },
        {
          "id": "94ec00b6-340f-4dc2-ab9b-f94a2f34c31f",
          "username": "Bernd"
        },
        {
          "id": "e357c7ff-941c-4f7d-9596-5dabc170fb15",
          "username": "Cedric"
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        {
          "id": "207d27e7-a65e-4d9e-93c9-b8fde509ce4f",
          "username": "Alex"
        },
        {
          "id": "94ec00b6-340f-4dc2-ab9b-f94a2f34c31f",
          "username": "Bernd"
        },
        {
          "id": "e357c7ff-941c-4f7d-9596-5dabc170fb15",
          "username": "Cedric"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Found my issue. The foreign key for the event host was pointing to the general auth table not to the users table. Now with that fixed I am able to fire this query.

client.from('events').select('*, host(id, username), guests(user_id(id, username))').eq('host', user.value.id).order('created_at')